# How do I select multiple tables in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf, linq

In SQL I have :

```
 SELECT gu.*, cu.*
 FROM [gene_genunit] as gu, [cont_unitati] as cu
 WHERE gu.COD_UNIT = cu.COD_UNIT
```

I have a WPF application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ARHIEntities ARHModel = new ARHIEntities(); // ARHIEntities is the model name
var qry = from gu in ARHModel.gene_genunit
          from cu in ARHModel.cont_unitati
          where gu.COD_UNIT == cu.COD_UNIT
          select new { cu, gu };
```

EDIT: added a `where` clause

Comment: This is a cross join and its not same as doing left join in sql.

Answer (score 6):

the LINQ equivalent would be

```
from gu in context.Gene
join cu in Context.Cont
on gu.Code_Unit equals cu.Code_Unit
select new 
{
   gu,
   cu
}
```

Use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to generate queries and to learn Linq

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't mention the 'FROM clause'" ?

Comment: @Misi ignore my comment about From clause. Just look at the code.