# mvc c# select from multiple table in lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I'm new to lambda and mvc c#. I'm using simple query using c#. Now I encountered this type of query and I don't know how to implement this lambda. There is no join in the multiple tables

```
select distinct sub.SubModuleName --[SMSSysmanager].
from    
        [dbo].tbl_Securable sec,
        [dbo].aspnet_UsersInRoles usr,
        [dbo].aspnet_Roles rol,
        [dbo].tbl_SubModule sub,
        [dbo].tbl_Module mod

where 
    usr.UserId=@userid and
    usr.roleID=sec.roleID and 
    rol.roleId=sec.roleID and
    rol.LoweredRoleName = LOWER(@RoleName) and
    sec.HasAccess=1 and 
    sec.ModuleId=sub.SubModuleId
```

Comment: See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: get a look at this question: [9273369](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273369/how-do-i-select-multiple-tables-in-linq)

Comment: I think it's hard to implement by lambda. You can separate them by some query.

Comment: In fact, `usr inner join sec, sec inner join rol, sec inner join sub`, I think it should have a missing clue that `sec inner join mod`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var distinctItems = (from sec in context.tbl_Securable
                 from usr in context.aspnet_UsersInRoles
                 from rol in context.aspnet_Roles
                 from sub in context.tbl_SubModule
                 from mod in context.tbl_Module
                 where
                     usr.UserId == userid &&
                     usr.roleID == sec.roleID &&
                     rol.roleId == sec.roleID &&
                     rol.LoweredRoleName == roleName.ToLower() &&
                     sec.HasAccess &&
                     sec.ModuleId == sub.SubModuleId
                 select
                     sub.SubModuleName).Distinct();
```